# Counting occurences across two tables and creating matrix of results

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new with mysql and php.  I have developed a hockey stat db.  Until now, I have been doing pretty basic queries and reporting of the stats.
I want to do a more complicated report and I am not even sure how to start it.  I have played around with temporary tables, foreach loops, and other things, but can seem to sort the logic/method out in my mind.

I have these tables:

```
players_table

player_id    |    name       
-------------------------------
1            |    Joe         
-------------------------------
2            |    Bill  
-------------------------------
3            |    Mike  
-------------------------------
4            |    Tom

1st_assists table

1st_assist_id    |     fk_goal_for_id   | fk_player_id
---------------------------------------------------------
1                |         1            |     2
---------------------------------------------------------
2                |         2            |     4


goals_for table

goal_for_id      |     fk_player_id
------------------------------------
1                |         1     
------------------------------------
2                |         2
```

Basically, I want to find out how many times each player had 1st_assists for each other player.  The end result would be like this:

```
Scoring_player_id   | 1st_assist_player:id1 | 1st_assist_player:id2 | 1st_assist_player:id3 | 1st_assist_player:id4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   |         X             |           1          |            0          |            0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2                   |         0             |           X          |            0          |            1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3                   |         0             |           0          |            X          |            0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4                   |         0             |           0          |            0          |            X
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

if it complicates things (I don't think it does), every goal will not necessarily have a 1st_assist.

Comment: Google:  "MySQL dynamic pivot".

Comment: Ah.  Thanks.  That might be the google search that opens the flood gates.  I will research and report back.

Comment: OK.  it took me a little time and I changed the output a little bit, but was able to accomplish what I wanted in terms of a result. example can be seen here:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/586b18/1